# Adding easing to the following jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, easing

I'm animating the height of element:

```
  // Animate height of items
  $j(".item .row").toggle(function(){
    $j(this).animate({height:500},200);
  },function(){
    $j(this).animate({height:300},200);
  });
```

I was wondering how to add easing to it? (e.g. the animation slowing down towards the end?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define easing, the following way

```
$('selector').animate({
    prop:1
},{
    easing: easing, //Something like 'linear'
    duration: duration,
    complete: callback
});
```

You can add other easing effects also, by including the [Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

In your case, it would be something like

```
$j(".item .row").toggle(function(){
    $j(this).animate({height:500}, {
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: '200'
    });
  },function(){
    $j(this).animate({height:300},{
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: '200'
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused about how to integrate that with my existing code. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try the plugin. I think 'linear' and 'swing' aren't the easing methods I'm looking for.